# How to get the content of floating title in SkyFloatingLabelTextField using XCUITest?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xcuitest, skyfloatinglabeltextfield

In my XCUITests I need to check content of floating title label in SkyFloatingLabelTextField after validation error.

I've set accessibilityIdentifier for SkyFloatingLabelTextField element, so I can tap and enter text into it without any issue, but how can I access its title (titleLabel?) using only XCUIElement?

I tried to set titleLabel as accessibilityElement with its own accessibilityIdentifier, but I wasn't able to access the text field in my tests after that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need add extension SkyFloatingLabelTextField:

```
extension SkyFloatingLabelTextField {
    override open var accessibilityIdentifier: String? {
        didSet {
            isAccessibilityElement = false
            titleLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
            titleLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = (accessibilityIdentifier ?? "") + "Title"
        }
    }
}
```

In controller you need add accessibilityIdentifier:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: SkyFloatingLabelTextField!
textField.accessibilityIdentifier = "YourTextFieldIdentifier"
```

If you want get title from textfild in your XCTestCase:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
let elementsQuery = app.scrollViews.otherElements

let getTitle = elementsQuery.textFields["YourTextFieldIdentifier"].staticTexts["YourTextFieldIdentifierTitle"]
            XCTAssertEqual(getTitle.label, "Your set title text")

elementsQuery.textFields["YourTextFieldIdentifier"].tap()
elementsQuery.textFields["YourTextFieldIdentifier"].typeText("Type text")
```

Answer (score -2):

A `SkyFloatingLabelTextField` inherits from `UITextField` so any method that works for `UITextField` should work for `SkyFloatingLabelTextField` too.